# Telegram бот-словарик на Python. Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог сам добавлять слова и их определения?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Создал Telegram бот-словарик на Python через BotFather.
Использовал библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI.
Пользователь вводит слово, если оно есть в коде, то он получает определение слова. Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог сам добавить слово и определение к нему?

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types

bot = TeleBot(token='Вставьте_свой_токен', parse_mode='html') # создание бота

DEFINITOINS = { }


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def start_command_handler(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id, # id чата, в который необходимо направить сообщение
        text='Привет! Подскажу определения слов из сферы тестирования \n'
             'Введите интересующий вас термин, например, баг')

@bot.message_handler() 
def message_handler(message: types.Message):
    definition = DEFINITOINS.get(message.text.lower())

    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text=' Я пока не знаю такого определения')
    # выходим из функции
    return

    # если ключевая фраза была найдена, формируем текст сообщения и отправляем его
    # если перед строкой поставить букву f, то в фигурных скобках 
    # {} можно использовать переменные :)
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text=f'Определение:\n<code>{definition}</code>')

    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text='Введите другой термин')
```

Comment: Я подредактировал формат, проверьте табуляцию и всё остальное

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо сначала сделать проверку на то, есть ли текст написанный пользователем в словаре.

```
if message.text.lower() in DEFINITIONS:
```

Затем, если определение уже есть в словаре, мы выводим пользователю перевод. Если же его нет, мы просто добавляем в словарь новую пару ключ/значение в формате:

```
DEFINITIONS['новый_ключ'] = 'новое_значение'
```

Вот небольшой пример консольного приложения:

```
definitions = {}
request = input('Введите запрос ')
if request in definitions:
    translation = definitions[request]
    print('Определение: ' + translation)
else:
    newTranslation = input('Определение не найдено. Введите его ')
    definitions[request] = newTranslation
```